# customize multicolumn footnote XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, footnotes, xepersian

I want customized footnote with this specification in document:

1. footnote number appear superscript in text body

(like: `foo` <sup>1</sup> `foo` <sup>2</sup> `foo` <sup>3</sup> `foo` <sup>4</sup>)

2. footnote number appear as normal number in footnote part

(like: `1. foot1     2. foot2     3. foot3     4.foot4`)

This is MWE i try it. I try writing (English/persian) document using
XePersian package and XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[extrafootnotefeatures]{xepersian}
\settextfont{B Nazanin}

% footnote customization code.
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makefntext#1{\parindent 1em
   \noindent\hbox to 2em{}%
   \llap{\@thefnmark.\,\,}#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{مقدمه}

% command for 2 column footnotes (when XePersian 
% package load with [extrafootnotefeatures], its 
% possible using this command) 
\twocolumnfootnotes

مدل
\RTLfootnote{
خلاصه‌ای از واقعیت را مدل گویند.
}

مدل
\LTRfootnote{Simulation is the imitation of the operation of ...}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found the right answer from [this Q/A website](http://www.qa.parsilatex.com/30278/), I should add this two
command before `begin{document}`:

```
\RTLfootmarkstyle{#1. }
\LTRfootmarkstyle{#1. }
```

And Finally

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[extrafootnotefeatures]{xepersian}
\settextfont{B Nazanin}

% footnote customization code.
\RTLfootmarkstyle{#1. }
\LTRfootmarkstyle{#1. }

\begin{document}

    \chapter{مقدمه}

    % command for 10 column footnotes (when XePersian 
    % package load with [extrafootnotefeatures], its 
    % possible using this command) 
    \tencolumnfootnotes

    مدل
    \RTLfootnote{
        خلاصه‌ای از واقعیت را مدل گویند.
    }

    مدل
    \LTRfootnote{Simulation is the imitation of the operation of ...}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`extrafootnotefeatures` somehow disable your footnote customization code. You can use `dblfnote` package to have two column footnote.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{dblfnote}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{B Nazanin}

% footnote customization code.
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makefntext#1{\parindent 1em
    \noindent\hbox to 2em{}%
    \llap{\@thefnmark.\,\,}#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \chapter{مقدمه}

    % command for 2 column footnotes (when XePersian 
    % package load with [extrafootnotefeatures], its 
    % possible using this command) 
    %\twocolumnfootnotes

    مدل
    \RTLfootnote{
        خلاصه‌ای از واقعیت را مدل گویند.
    }

    مدل
    \LTRfootnote{Simulation is the imitation of the operation of ...}


\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, BUT I Want multi-column (mean three,... ten column) Not Just two column.